# replace entire line containing text or symbol (notepad++)

Tags: notepad++

I wanted to know if it were possible to replace the entire line of text if it contains a symbol.  For example, I have a bunch of different programs in a folder and they all begin with %xxxx (the xs are #s so some are %0001, some are %0030, and so on).  Without having go search/replace all 100 possibilities one-by-one is it possible to replace any ENTIRE line containing % with O0001?

Comment: Please, [edit your question](https://superuser.com/posts/1713436/edit) and add sample text and expected result.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do this using regex:
[image]

Here I search for symbol "c" and replace the entire line with "qqqqqq"
Do not forget to select below in Search Mode -> Regular Expression.

In your case the regex should be something like:

```
^%00[0-9]{2}(.*)
```

Comment: So, if I am reading it correctly, if I did:  find what: (.*)%(.*) replace with o0001, it would replace every entire line that has a % in it with o0001?

Comment: @Scott, correct. But if you search for more specific string you should create more complex regex like `^%00[0-9]{2}(.*)` to search for `%` in the begin of line, followed by `00` then followed by any two numbers